# manipulating one element in a list in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of 200 data points.  I want to select one value, and change the data using the manipulate function to create a bad data point, and observe the effects on the graph.

My recent attempts included creating a variable i, and assigning like:

```
myarray[[80,2]] = i;
```

and then use manipulate as such:

```
Manipulate[Curve[myarray], {i, 0, 5}]
```

This is not giving the desired output, however.  It doesn't really make sense to me to put it like that, but I don't see the alternative way.  Any help on this particular problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making up some data and a `Curve` function :-

```
myarray = Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10]/2}];
Curve[myarray_] := ListLinePlot[myarray]
Manipulate[myarray[[8, 2]] = i; Curve[myarray], {i, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!  I do have one other question though.  is it possible to create the manipulate like this?  Manipulate[myarray[[8, 2]] = i; somefunction[myarray], {i, 0, 5}]?  I need to pass myarray to another function, and it has to be manipulated inside that function.  I'm a bit new to mathematica, so I don't know if this is a built in feature of manipulate.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I see you did exactly that in your post.  Everything worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Chris Degnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879601/chris-degnen)'s answer, which shows a good approach, here is an explanation for why your original code failed.

`Manipulate`, like `Module`, acts as a scoping construct.  For this reason the `i` used by `Manipulate` (the manipulation variable) is not the *same* `i` as set with `myarray[[80, 2]] = i;` -- it exists in a different [`Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Context.html):

```
Manipulate[Context[i], {i, 0, 5}]

(* FE` *)
```

Here is a minimal example of the problem:

```
ClearAll[x, i]
x = i;
Manipulate[{x, i}, {i, 0, 5}]

(* {i, 2.24} *)
```

One way around this is to use `Block`, but you need to use a different name for the manipulate variable:

```
ClearAll[x, i]
x = {1, 2, i};
Manipulate[Block[{i = ii}, x], {ii, 0, 5}]

(* {1, 2, 1.41} *)
```